# Weird Fish Prompt

Tags: shell, fish

I am using fish as my primary shell; along with [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish)

Now the first character on the fish prompt is really weird `[I]` as shown in the picture[image: Fish Prompt]

Kindly help me get rid of the character.

Comment: Is that the vi insert-mode indicator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the vi mode indicator. It shows that you are using vi key bindings, and are currently in insert mode.

If you don't want to use vi bindings, and instead use the default (emacs) style, you can run `fish_default_key_bindings` to switch back.

If you want vi key bindings, but want to hide the mode indicator, you can define the `fish_mode_prompt` function as empty, and then save it:

```
> function fish_mode_prompt ; end
> funcsave fish_mode_prompt
```